# Excel VBA records nothing if I change the picture

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to imitate "Change picture..." behaviour through VBA macro by simply recoding a macro and seeing how it is done. However when I looked at code it gave me this:

```
    Sub ReplacePicture()
'
' ReplacePicture Macro
'

'

End Sub
```

If I insert two pictures and change them it records:

```
Sub ReplacePicture()
'
' ReplacePicture Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert( _
        "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Pictures\Some.png" _
        ).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 71
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -207
    Range("U7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 3")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 6")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 3")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 6")).Select
    Range("R7").Select
End Sub
```

Changing picture leaves no trace in VBA!
Why is that and can I mimic that behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by "change a picture"? Do you edit it, or change its dimensions?

Comment: I mean change the source file for the picture instead of "Some.png" to "SomeOtherPic.png"

Comment: VBA does not record everything. In such a case, that `Change` option practically reinserts another picture...